# In PySpark, I need to transform a column (list of Maps) into a string, within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, transformation

This is an example of a row I have:

```
# Example Row
{
  "random_column": [
    {
      "abc": "..."
    },
    {
      "def": "..."
    },
    {
      "ghi": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is an example of what I need:

```
# Needed Transformation
{
  "random_column": "abc,def,ghi"
}
```

While I could do this easily outside of pandas, how do you do this within a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Do you want concatenate only the keys?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform` with `map_keys` to get the map key of each array element, and combine the keys into a single string using `concat_ws`:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'random_column', 
    F.expr("concat_ws(',', transform(random_column, x -> map_keys(x)[0]))")
)

df2.show()
+-------------+
|random_column|
+-------------+
|  abc,def,ghi|
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to concatenate all map keys:

```py
(df
 .withColumn('random_column_keys', f.expr("REDUCE(random_column, cast(array() as array<string>), (acc, el) -> array_union(acc, map_keys(el)), acc -> concat_ws(',', acc))"))
 .show(truncate=False))
```

Output:

```
+------------------------------------------+------------------+
|random_column                             |random_column_keys|
+------------------------------------------+------------------+
|[{abc -> ...}, {def -> ...}, {ghi -> ...}]|abc,def,ghi       |
+------------------------------------------+------------------+
```